# How to perform sequential service calls?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to call 2 services and the second one needs to be called with the data retrieved by the first one.
The first service returns an array of objects which contains the category ID and for each ID I need to use a second service in order to get the items associated with said ID.
The problem is that when the "items" service is used the subscription doesn't seem to work.

I already tried to nest the second call in the first one in order to have a merged Observable but without any result.

```
categoriesArray: Category[];
categoryItemsArray: [CategoryItem[]];

this.firstService
      .query({ 'sectionId.equals': this.section.id })
      .pipe(
        filter((res: HttpResponse<Category[]>) => res.ok),
        map((res: HttpResponse<Category[]>) => res.body))
      .subscribe(
        categories => {
          this.categoriesArray = categories;
        },
        error => console.error(error),
        () => {
          this.categoriesArray.forEach(( category, index) => {
            console.log('entered ForEach loop');
            this.secondService.query({ 'categoryId.equals': category.id })
            .pipe(
              filter((res: HttpResponse<CategoryItem[]>) => res.ok),
              map((res: HttpResponse<CategoryItem[]>) => res.body))
            .subscribe( (categoryItems, index) => {
             console.log('second subscribe');
             this.categoryItemsArray[index] = categoryItems;             
            });
          });
      });
```

The second subscribe is never reached.

Comment: The this.categoriesArray.forEach( will only run if its and error in the call to firstService.

Comment: Use the switchMap operator. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't subscribe within a subscription. After the beginning:

```
this.firstService
      .query({ 'sectionId.equals': this.section.id })
      .pipe(
        filter((res: HttpResponse<Category[]>) => res.ok),
        map((res: HttpResponse<Category[]>) => res.body),
```

we switch to another stream, with the `switchMap` operator like this:

```
        switchMap(categories => forkJoin(
            categories.map(this.requestSingleCategory)
        ))
```

here *n* requests are sent simultaneously. What's left is to subscribe and consume the results:

```
    ).subscribe((categoryItems) => this.categoryItemsArray = categoryItems);
```

I refactored `requestSingleCategory` into separate function for readibility's sake:

```
private requestSingleCategory = ({ id }) => this.secondService.query({ 'categoryId.equals': id });
```

(There's a fair chance my parentheses count is off).

Comment: This is the part I changed after your suggestion:  `switchMap(categories => forkJoin(
          categories.map( category => {
            this.functionToGetItems(category.id);
            }
          )
        ))
      ).subscribe( categoryItems => this.categoryItemsArray = categoryItems); ` but it's not working. In the browser console I also get the current error "ERROR TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.". I also tried to assign categoriesArray instead of categoryItemsArray but nothing changed.

Comment: Well, it shouldn't work. There's no value returned from function `category => { this.functionToGetItems(category.id); } `. Lose the enclosing `{ }`.